# android basic auth okhttpclient

Tags: android, tomcat, retrofit, basic-authentication, okhttp

I am connecting to my rest api using retrofit and okHttp client. When I disable Basic authentication on Tomcat everything works flawlessly. 
When Basic Auth is enabled on Tomcat I get 404 Page not found.
Here is my authentication and error output.

```
    okHttpClient.setAuthenticator(new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        public Request authenticate(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
            String credential = Credentials.basic(rest_user, rest_pw);
            return response.request().newBuilder().header("Authorization", credential).build();
        }

        @Override
        public Request authenticateProxy(Proxy proxy, Response response) throws IOException {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

Error log

```
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: <--- HTTP 404 https://myserver:8443/RestWS/objects/barcodes (4462ms)
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: Cache-Control: private
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=*********************; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: Content-Length: 127
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: Date: Tue, 26 Apr 2016 09:31:22 GMT
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1461663081883
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1461663081973
    D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: <html>
            D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: <head>
            D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: <title>404-Page Not Found</title>
            D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: </head>
            D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: <body> The requested URL was not found on this server. </body>
            D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: </html>
            D/YOUR_LOG_TAG: <--- END HTTP (127-byte body)
```

Comment: It shows that the page you are looking for is missing on the server side. You should check on backend.

Comment: It is there I am opening it without problem when I disale auth. When auth is enabled I can access this page from browser from android I can not

Comment: The must be needed some authorization to get access, so you will have to authorize it always before accessing it in android. You need to pass the authorization credentials in header.

Comment: You are right, but I am passing this okhttp client to retrofit, through which I am making all requests, and they all fail, even when I am passing header with Authorization and credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved using RequestInterceptor.

```
  restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .setRequestInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor() {
                @Override
                public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
                    String credentials = DownloadService.rest_user + ":" + DownloadService.rest_pw;
                    String base64EncodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64EncodedCredentials);
                }
            })
            .setEndpoint(DownloadService.URL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(okHttpClient))
            .build();
```